# how to import the all products of another site into magento site

Tags: php, magento

hi can any body help me please..i have installed magento on live server and now i want to import all products and category of a website which is allready running live.. how can i do it please any help....

Answer (score 1):

See the Magento Wiki:

- [How to add/edit/remove products using the import/export tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/import_export/export_tool)

Magento is rather special, so [you might have more luck getting answers at their Forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/). Also [search through the Magento Knowledgebase](http://www.google.com/search?q=import+export+site%3Amagentocommerce.com).

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box tool does not import Categories. There are a lot of modules on MagentoConnect that also import categories. You can also try unirgy.com uRapidFlow.

Answer (score 1):

Importing into Magento is not a trivial task. You can use their import/export tool but I find it slow and cumbersome. There's an open source importer called [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) which works with categories.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 3rd party service to export products database from one server to another
http://importexportbridge.xpscommerce.com/

There required to specify source server address, API username, password and destination server details to transfer database data.

Products, attributes, images data going to be transfered automatically to destination server.