# how can i import all product of another website in my website running in magento

Tags: php, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to import the all products of another site into magento site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214118/how-to-import-the-all-products-of-another-site-into-magento-site)

i have created two website in magento according my client requirement.now i want to import all the product which are running in another website.in to my created website in magento how can i do it.please some body provide me solution.help will be greatfull...thanks

Comment: A little more information might be helpful... like what system the other website is running on.

Comment: You already asked that: [how to import the all products of another site into magento site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214118/how-to-import-the-all-products-of-another-site-into-magento-site)

Comment: the another website is running on asp.net in microsoft plateform..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like always when migrating data between systems you need to do an export from one website and then import that data into the other. Magento will accept csv as input data and your other system should be able to export csv. If not, you should have no problems preparing a csv export working directly on the DB.